# How to query data form parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to get data from parse.com and validate is a record exists and if so perform a segue.

This is my test code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"codes"];
[query whereKey:@"code" equalTo:_code.text];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
    // comments now contains the comments for myPost
    if (comments) {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Fail!");
    }
}];
```

Solution:

```
NSString *code1 = _code.text;
NSNumber *code2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[code1 integerValue]];
// Assume PFObject *myPost was previously created.
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"present_codes"];
[query whereKey:@"code" equalTo:@([code2 integerValue])];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
    // comments now contains the comments for myPost
    if (comments.count > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Success!: %@", comments);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Fail!: %@", comments);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes the value in the log is always Success but there is not value in the class like that I im not sure how to validate properly. - Thanks for your reply.

Comment: So what does the `comments` array contain?

Comment: Nothing it is blank but the log is Success.

Comment: So you want `if (comments.count > 0) {` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that did not work and no data is returning

Comment: thanks for all your replays, I have solved the issue.